# Most accurate affirmative form of a sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis, negation

The sentence is

**I can never forget you.**

We have to find the affirmative form of this sentence without changing its meaning.

I can think of two answers for this question.

1.**I will always remember you.**

2.**I can hardly forget you.**

Which sentence is the closest to the original sentence in meaning? I feel it must be the first one, since **hardly** introduces a factor of uncertainty, though negligible.

Comment: I agree with your analysis.

Comment: I think _will_ is better than _can_; it involves an act of personal will, which is what's called for. (I'm assuming this is to be a leave-taking phrase, like Spanish _Nunca te olvideré_.)

Comment: Depends on how you parse the sentence.  There are two ways of reading it, one of which is already affirmative: *I'm capable of never forgetting you* vs *I'm never capable of forgetting you*. The latter indicates the necessity of remembering, but the in the former, though you are capable, there's no indication you will.

Comment: I'm not sure many native English speakers would use the original sentence. It would usually be either _I can't ever forget you_ or _I will never forget you._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "I will always remember you" is unmistakably an affirmative alternative to "I can never forget you," with "remember" as the affirmative action. But "I can hardly forget you" isn't really expressed affirmatively at all; rather, in essence, it negates the word *forget* in the sentence without explicitly using the word *not* to handle the job. Replacing *never* with *hardly* doesn't change the denial of the following verb *forget*, because *hardly* amounts to saying *not easily*, which, when attached to *forget*, looks like a negation to me.

So I agree with you (and with Dan Bron) that "I will always remember you" is a much better example of an affirmative alternative to "I can never forget you" than "I can hardly forget you" is.